# How does percentage work in grid items min-width [when using fit-content]?

Tags: css, css-grid

Goal

- Have a CSS grid container
- Have 3 columns calculated by fit-content(33.33%), to get equally sized columns
- Being able to control/clamp column size further by using min/max-width on indivudal grid items

In particular I want to adjust the size of columns from 33% to 50% in case there are only 2 grid items, *by using min-width*.

**The snippet below meets the goals above**.

```css
.grid {
  width: 780px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, fit-content(33.33%));
  justify-items: start;
  align-items: stretch;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.cell {
  min-width:calc(780px / 2);
  height:80vh;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%,
    rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I use an explicit value: `min-width:calc(780px / 2)`.

So I tried using percentage, e.g. `min-width:calc(100% / 2)`. But it seems like percentage here in the grid item is relative to it's own width and **not** the container's width.

So I tried this: `min-width:calc(300% / 2)`, thinking that if 100% is the width of 1 grid item in a fit-content 1/3, then 300% / 2 would be roughly 50% min-width relative to the containers width.

But using percentage like this makes the items to overlap:

```css
.grid {
  width: 780px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, fit-content(33.33%));
  justify-items: start;
  align-items: stretch;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.cell {
  min-width:calc(300% / 2);
  height:80vh;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%,
    rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

So my question is: is it possible to use percentage in a grid item's min-width, relative to the container's width? How?

Comment: Is it a hard requirement to use CSS Grid and min-width in the solution? If all you want is a container that equally distributes 2 or 3 columns then that can be trivially solved just using flexbox.

Comment: Yes, I need CSS grid and min-width due to many other requirements (this case is very isolated). I'm also really curious how percentage work here because it's equally weird in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct, `min-width` used with percentage is relative to the grid cell already defined by `33%` of the grid container so you need `300%/2` to have `50%` BUT you will overflow the grid cell which is defined by `33%`. To fix this, you may consider adding `margin-right` to the second element to push it since the second cell start at `33%` and not `50%` like you may think due to overflow.

The margin should be equal to `50%` which will be `50%` of `33%`, thus `16.5%` of the container which is also `50% - 33%` like shown in the figure below:

```css
.grid {
  width: 780px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, fit-content(33.33%));
  justify-items: start;
  align-items: stretch;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.cell {
  min-width:calc(300% / 2);
  height:80vh;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%,
    rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%
  );
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This is the best workaround I think. But it is odd that using percentages doesn't change the size of the grid item / cell. While using `min-width:calc(780px / 2)` *changes the cell size* and prevents overflow. I've never seen different units change the behaviour drastically.

Comment: Using `margin-left` is not as good as if percentages was able to change the cell size just like exact units, because it's not enough if you use `max-width` too (which fit-content should respect). E.g. you change `min-width` to `width` (because `min-width` has precedence over `max-width`) and add a `max-width` of 400px. You would need to set the margin to (pseudo code) `calc(max(100%, (400px - widthOfGridItem) * 2) / 2)` in order to get a) 50% margin if max-width is not reached or b) the max-width minus the cell width

Comment: @Bell `I've never seen different units change the behaviour drastically` --> simply because px are percentage aren't the same ... using px you are considering a non-relative lenght so it works intuitively BUT when you use % it's a relative length and it's not relative to the container but to the track defined by a percentage and logically you cannot increase a specified width using a percentage width defined with the first specified width (I know it's not easy to get) that's why the only way is to have overflow which is also logical when using more than 100%

Answer (score -1):

Would this work for you ?

```css
.grid {
  width: 780px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  justify-items: start;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.cell {
  height: 80vh;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 0%,
    rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div> 
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't use `fit-content`.